# asp.net website where one page needs localization at user option

Tags: asp.net, localization

Most information and posts about localization deal with the entire site. My need is simpler, just one page from an entire site which uses .net 4.5.

I have created a resx for the page. I want a dropdown list to choose language from. I want the resx file for Spanish to be applied to the page if the user clicks the Spanish button, and revert back to the default English if they choose that item. I'm writing in vb.

I can't seem to find anything that deals with the idea of allowing the use to localize one page at their option.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how it will be on VB exactly, but I may describe what you have to do.
Create Dropdownlist: text of Items will be as you want (in your case it is language names), as values of this items take their culture (US English: en-US, Russian ru-RU, so on). You have to set up AutoPostBack of dropdownlist to true. On every AutoPostBack you have to do: Open Resx file -> Localize();
In C# in will looks like:

```
txtItIsPageBodysDescription.Text = GlobalResourceObject("path_to_resx_file_"+ddlLanguages.SelectedValue, "string_from_resource).ToString();
```

And you should remember that for every language you have to create resource files. And call them like *resource_en-US*, *resource_ru-RU*, so on. If you have any questions, or you need the full example, just contact me via email xazratbek@gmail.com. I will try to help you. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Are you saying that for every textbox or other control which needs localization I need to pull the text from the resx file? That's what it looks like from your example. That would be a lot of work...isn't there a way to apply the resx values for the selected language to the entire page? I have everything else completed, the dropdownlist, the resx file, just don't know how to apply to one page at the user's option via the ddl.

Comment: @meridian you can do like as in article by the link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw69ke6f.aspx , but there is one aspect: on that article you may see automatic localization, which means that your controls will be localized depending on browser settings. If you will use that, you can't provide manual language choosing to user. For example, if you are sitting in internet-cafe in Indonesia, web-site might be displayed in Indonesian automatically, but you need change to English, but you can't do that. You will have to change browser settings. That's one problem.

Comment: What I did was to set a cookie to the desired language, and then wrote a sub which overrides InitializeCulture, checks for the cookie value, and then sets the CurrentUICulture. It works great.

Comment: @meridian Well done! But also consider, that user might be disabled the cookies. Actually, for any user u can take his mac-address and save his language in database: even if he disabled the cookies, you will be able to display him the same language every time.